# select/deselect button in asp.net by last selected first deselect

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have dynamically created buttons as shown in code all all the button from 10:00 to 12:00 with 15 min of interval and deselect in lifo order like if i have selected 10:0 and 10:15 then i can not select 10:45 .. and i i have selected 10:0,10:15,10:30,10:45 and then i have to deselect 10:15 then first we have to deselect 10:30 and 10:45 ...please help me out.

```
   private void GetControls()
    {
        count++;
        for (int i = 10; i < 12; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 60; j += 15)
            {
                Button btn = new Button();
                btn.Text = i + "-" + j;
                btn.ID = i + "-" + j;
                btn.Command += new CommandEventHandler(this.btn_Click);
               // btn.Click += btn_Click;
                flag = true;
                btn.CommandName = i + "-" + j;
                if (count==1)
                {
                    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(btn);
                }
             }
       }   

    }

    private void btn_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        count++;

        string ID = (sender as Button).ID;
        Label1.Text = " Congrates! Your meeting time has been sheduled upto " + ID;
        Label1.Visible = false;
        Button btn = sender as Button;


        if (btn.BackColor == Color.Green)
        {
            btn.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
            getStatus(sender);

        }

        else
        {
            btn.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong! You want to only select one button at a time so that if one button is clicked, the rest should reset? if that's the case, here's a code to do so:

---

[Edit]

Added a Session to remember dynamic button ids and used (.) instead of (-) for button Ids

```
private void GetControls()
    {
        count++;
        for (int i = 10; i < 12; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 60; j += 15)
            {
                Button btn = new Button();
                btn.Text = i + "-" + j;
                btn.ID = i + "." + j;
                btn.Command += new CommandEventHandler(this.btn_Click);
                // btn.Click += btn_Click;
                flag = true;
                btn.CommandName = i + "-" + j;
                if (count == 1)
                {
                    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(btn);
                    List<string> createdControls = Session["Controls"] != null ? Session["Controls"] as List<string> : new List<string>();
                    if (!createdControls.Contains(btn.ID)) createdControls.Add(btn.ID);
                    Session["Controls"] = createdControls;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

[Edited] Replace the btn-Click event with the following.

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        count++;
        string ID = (sender as Button).ID;
        ResetButton(Convert.ToDouble(ID));
        Label1.Text = " Congrates! Your meeting time has been sheduled upto " + ID;
        Button btn = sender as Button;

        if (btn.BackColor == Color.Green)
        {
            btn.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;


        }

        else
        {
            btn.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;

        }
    }
```

[Edited] And this is the method implementation

```
private void ResetButton(double selectedButtonID)
        {
            List<string> createdControls = Session["Controls"] != null ? Session["Controls"] as List<string> : new List<string>();
            TimeSpan timespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(selectedButtonID);
            string currentSelectedTime = timespan.ToString("h\\:mm");
            foreach (string buttonID in createdControls)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(buttonID))
                {
                    int comparisonResult = timespan.CompareTo(TimeSpan.FromHours(Convert.ToDouble(buttonID)));
                    Button button = Page.FindControl(buttonID) as Button;
                    if (button != null && comparisonResult==1)
                    {
                        button.BackColor = Color.Yellow;// selected
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        button.BackColor = Color.Red;// deselected
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: noo actually i have been making project on doctos sheduing page and he demands that You can select time from 10:15 to 10:45 .in continuous way ..not like that one has selected 10:15 and then on right time he has selected 10 :45 in between all are deselected .that would be bad case ..in one word i if i want to deselect one button then firstly i have to deselect other button whose timings comes after that like to deselect 10:30 i have to deselect 10:45 ,11:00 if selected

Comment: So what I understood is: if button 10:30 is selected, you would expect that 10:00 and 10:15 to be selected as well. And the rest of the buttons (i.e. from 10:45 to 11:45) should be all deselected.

Comment: okk i have generated button from 1 to 8 dynamically and then if i select button 2,3,4,5,6 then i want to deselect 4th button so i have to deselect 5th 6th 7th button ..then only i would be able to deselect 4th button
so i want solution

Comment: An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code when u r changing id to double

Comment: Hello solution seeker. This formatException is generated if you try to run the code without making the changes I suggested in GetControls method. If you notice, I have used . (dot) instead of dash (-) to assign an id for the dynamic button. So the correct syntax as I posted is:  btn.ID = i + "." + j;

Comment: hello sir , thanks for the answer i have implemented it in my code and it works but now my client get disagree , he is saying that select button in continuous way rathar then selecting it from starting ..i.e. he means that he select 3,4,5,6 in this manner and if he want to deselect 5 then compulsaraily he has to deselect 6 also .....i think we can set boolean value in list which contain all the selected button and then check from it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112849/discussion-between-solution-seeker-and-gh-karim).