# How to select(changing color) dynamically created button in continuous way without skip

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have dynamically created buttons, eg 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8; if I select 2,3,4, then I can't select 6 and skip 4. Or you can say, if I select 2,3,4,5,6 then if want to deselect 4 then I have to deselect 5 and 6 first.

```
    private void GetControls()
    {
        count++;
        for (int i = 10; i < 12; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 60; j += 15)
            {
                Button btn = new Button();
                btn.Text = i + "-" + j;
                btn.ID = i + "." + j;
                btn.Command += new CommandEventHandler(this.btn_Click);
               // btn.Click += btn_Click;
                flag = true;
                btn.CommandName = i + "-" + j;
                if (count==1)
                {
                    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(btn);

                    List<string> createdControls = Session["Controls"] != null ? Session["Controls"] as List<string> : new List<string>();
                    if (!createdControls.Contains(btn.ID)) createdControls.Add(btn.ID);
                    Session["Controls"] = createdControls;
                }
             }
       }   

    }

    private void btn_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        count++;
        //ResetButton();
        Button btn = sender as Button;
        string ID = (sender as Button).ID;
        string text = (sender as Button).Text;
        ResetButton(Convert.ToDouble(ID));
        Label1.Text = " Congrates! Your meeting time has been sheduled between " + ID;


    }  //}
    private void ResetButton(double selectedButtonID)
    {
        List<string> createdControls = Session["Controls"] != null ? Session["Controls"] as List<string> : new List<string>();
        TimeSpan timespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(selectedButtonID);
        string currentSelectedTime = timespan.ToString("h\\:mm");
        foreach (string buttonID in createdControls)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(buttonID))
            {
                int comparisonResult = timespan.CompareTo(TimeSpan.FromHours(Convert.ToDouble(buttonID)));
                Button button = Page.FindControl(buttonID) as Button;
                if (button != null && comparisonResult >= 0 )
                {

                    if (button.BackColor == Color.Yellow)
                    {
                        button.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.GhostWhite;
                    }

                    else if (button.BackColor == Color.GhostWhite)
                    {
                        button.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.GhostWhite;

                    }
                    else
                    {

                        button.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                    }
```

Comment: So what you want to do is being only able to select a button if all his predecesors are selected? Like to select 4 you need 1,2 and 3 selected? And for deselect 4 you need 5 and 6 to be deselected?

Comment: actually i can deselect predecesor like if i have selected 1,2,3,4,5,6 then i can deselect 1,then 2,then 3 but i cannot deselect 3 without deselecting 1 and 2 or i can deselect 4 and 5 to deselect 3

Comment: in one sentence i can select in continuous way only like 5,6,7,8 not like 5,6,8

Comment: Oh, that's what happens and not what you want it to do? What do you want to do, that any button to be select independently?

Comment: yesssss ....but condition is only in continuous manner eg if i have selected 2,3,4,5,6,7,8 in these if some one want to deselect  6 then we can only do this by deselection 7,8 button .

Comment: may be ..we can also solve it by assigning all selected value to false and then compare it with preceder and succeceder if both value contain false then select/deselect bt dont no it will work or not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [select/deselect button in asp.net by last selected first deselect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37412418/select-deselect-button-in-asp-net-by-last-selected-first-deselect)