# how to select/deselect dynamically created button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have dynamically created buttons, e.g 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8; if I select 2,3,4, then I can't select 6 and skip 4. Or you can say, if I select 2,3,4,5,6 then if want to deselect 4 then I have to deselect 5 and 6 first. means if once we selected then we can only deselect it by either from left most side or right

```
     private void GetControls()
          {
    count++;
    for (int i = 10; i < 12; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 60; j += 15)
        {
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Text = i + "-" + j;
            btn.ID = i + "." + j;
            btn.Command += new CommandEventHandler(this.btn_Click);
           // btn.Click += btn_Click;
            flag = true;
            btn.CommandName = i + "-" + j;
            if (count==1)
            {
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(btn);


            }
         }
   }   

}

private void btn_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    count++;
    //ResetButton();
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    string ID = (sender as Button).ID;
    string text = (sender as Button).Text;

    Label1.Text = " Congrates! Your meeting time has been sheduled between "                                              + ID;


}  

                if (button.BackColor == Color.Yellow)
                {
                    button.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.GhostWhite;
                }

                else if (button.BackColor == Color.GhostWhite)
                {
                    button.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.GhostWhite;

                }
                else
                {

                    button.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                }
```

Comment: What do you mean `deselect`? Visibility or enable/disable?

Comment: to change the color only and neglect unwanted code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select(changing color) dynamically created button in continuous way without skip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37429462/how-to-selectchanging-color-dynamically-created-button-in-continuous-way-witho)